# And there was I, thinking that Stack Exchange ads were automatically generated

Tags: discussion, advertising

Or are they?

[image]

Comment: They are not...

Comment: "V.S." -- what does Visual Studio have to do with anything?

Answer (score 2):

Some are, some are not.